# Derive parametric equation for $x^2+y^2=9z^2$

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

Could somebody show me any ideas how this $$x^2+y^2=9z^2$$ can be transformed into parametric form?

Comment: With only a single parameter, you'll only be able to describe a one-dimensional curve in space. But this is a two dimensional cone... Are you sure you shouldn't be using another parameter, like $u$?

Comment: Maybe I should, because it is just said to "derive parametric equation". My equations with $t$ is just my interpretation.

Comment: Ah, OK. Then yes, I would use $t$ and $u$ as parameters. The "boring" way would be to let $x(t,u) = t,\ y(t,u) = u$ and calculate $z$ from that, but there are many other ways: using circular cross-sections, or sets of lines, etc, as families of one-dimensional curves that make up the surface.

Comment: Ok, I liked the way of $t$ and $u$. Could you please show the first step to me?

Comment: @pjs36 I need your help ;P

Comment: Working on a little something now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a fixed non-zero value of $z=c$, your equation describes a circle in the plane $z=c$ with radius $3c$. You probably know that a parametrization of a circle can be given by sine and cosine. Taking the varying $z$ into account, we get

$$x=3u\cos t$$
$$y=3u\sin t$$
$$z=u$$
$$t\in [0,2\pi),\ u\in (-\infty,\infty)$$

There are other ways to do this, of course. Note that for $u=0$, all values of $t$ give the same answer $x=0,y=0,z=0$. For non-zero $u$ and the given domain for $t$, the values are distinct.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter: Yes, you are correct. I have now adjusted my equations appropriately. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: Now it seems so obvious after your explanation, thank you very much)

Comment: @RoryDaulton by the way, now it looks to me that your set of equations describes some kind of spiral instead of a cone, because we dont control the relative rate of change of two parameters... Shouldn't we introduce some new equation to allow change of $u$ after $t$ passed $2\pi$

Comment: @blitzar787: This is a parametrization, so $t$ and $u$ vary independently of each other. The given domains are the *only* restrictions on $t$ and $u$. If $t$ and $u$ are independent, you get the same double cone as your equation. If $t$ and/or $u$ are limited in some way, you get a subset of that double cone. Is this clear?

Comment: @RoryDaulton thanks, for explanation, you helped very much.

Comment: @blitzar787: Perhaps I should say that the usual variables for a two-dimensional parametrization are $u$ and $v$. I used $t$ and $u$ in this answer due to comments by pjs36 and you.

Comment: @RoryDaulton thx, for keeping it in style)